# Template isn't rendered with Django

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having issues rendering a modal popup dialog as a template with Underscore and Backbone on a Django website, otherwise it works as a standalone single page app. Why would that be?

Here is a snippet of the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="popup-template">
<div class="modal sector-popup" style="background-color:#f5f5f5; visibility:visible;">
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
    <input type="image" class="pull-right" id="closebtn" src="../media/x-button.png" data-dismiss="modal">
    ...
</div>
</script>
```

And here is where it is used in the website:

```
window.FormPopup = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#popup-template').html()),

    events: {
            "dblclick .sector-label" : "edit",
            "keypress .sector-label-edit input" : "setLabel"
            },

    render: function() {
            var view = this;
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    ...
    },
  });
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: A popup dialog should appear as a result of a click. It all works fine until I try to integrate it into a django app. I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

Comment: Are you getting JavaScript errors? Malformed HTML?

Comment: Is the template making it to the page? Is the Underscore markup conflicting with Django's template markup to produce a mess?

Comment: No errors in the console. It does seem to appear at the end of the html as it should but it doesn't actually render on the page. I'm not sure where else to look to check why.